# PyDeadObjectError and StatusBar

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

Recently I moved from Debian to Mac OS X (Yosemite), and after starting my application getting error in terminal while running:

```
relrin at MacBook-Relrin in ~/code/Helenae/Helenae/helenae/gui on git:dev+? workon code 
=> run_wx.sh CloudStorage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/Helenae/Helenae/helenae/gui/widgets/Filemanager.py", line 286, in OnSize
    self.sb.SetStatusText(os.getcwd())
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/Helenae/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_core.py", line 16711, in __getattr__
    raise PyDeadObjectError(self.attrStr % self._name)
wx._core.PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of the StatusBar object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed.
```

However in Debian this application didn't say about any errors. How can I fix this issue?

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import wx
import shutil
import ntpath

from FileListCtrl import FileListCtrl
from OptionsCtrl import OptionsCtrl
from InputDialogCtrl import InputDialog
from validators.FolderValidator import FolderValidator
from validators.FileValidator import FileValidator
from validators.ValidatorMsgDlg import ValidatorMsgDialog as MsgDlg

ID_BUTTON = 100
ID_BUTTON_WRITE = 101
ID_BUTTON_TRANSFER = 102
ID_BUTTON_CREATE_FOLDER = 103
ID_BUTTON_REMOVE_FILE = 104
ID_BUTTON_RENAME = 105
ID_NEW = 150
ID_FOLDER = 151
ID_RENAME = 152
ID_REPLACE = 153
ID_REMOVE = 154
ID_SHOW_STATUSBAR = 155
ID_OPTIONS = 156
ID_WRITE = 157
ID_COPY_FILE = 158
ID_COPY_FOLDER = 159
ID_EXIT = 200
ID_SPLITTER = 300
ID_TOOLBAR_UPDIR = 201
ID_TOOLBAR_HOME = 202
ID_TOOLBAR_REFRESH = 203
ID_TOOLBAR_HELP = 204

class FileManager(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, ico_folder):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        self.parent = parent
        self.ico_folder = ico_folder
        wx.Log.SetLogLevel(0)

        # file frame
        self.files_folder = FileListCtrl(self, -1, ico_folder)
        # options frame
        self.options_frame = OptionsCtrl(self, -1, "Опции", ico_folder)

        # menu
        filemenu= wx.Menu()
        newItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_NEW, "&Новый файл", help='Создать новый файл в каталоге')
        newItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/new.png'))
        createItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_FOLDER, "&Создать каталог", help='Создать новый каталог')
        createItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/folder.png'))
        copyFileItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_COPY_FILE, "&Скопировать файл", help='Скопировать файл извне в текущий каталог')
        copyFileItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/copy_file.png'))
        copyFolderItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_COPY_FOLDER, "&Скопировать каталог", help='Скопировать каталог извне в текущий каталог')
        copyFolderItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/copy_folder.png'))
        renameItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_RENAME, "&Перемеиновать", help='Перемеиновать выделенный файл')
        renameItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/rename.png'))
        removeItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_REPLACE, "&Перенос", help='Перенести выделенные файлы в другой каталог')
        removeItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/remove.png'))
        writeItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_WRITE, "&Запись", help='Записать выделенные файлы')
        writeItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/write.png'))
        deleteItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_REMOVE, "&Удалить", help='Удалить выделенные файлы')
        deleteItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/delete.png'))
        filemenu.AppendItem(newItem)
        filemenu.AppendItem(createItem)
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.AppendItem(copyFileItem)
        filemenu.AppendItem(copyFolderItem)
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.AppendItem(renameItem)
        filemenu.AppendItem(removeItem)
        filemenu.AppendItem(writeItem)
        filemenu.AppendItem(deleteItem)
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        exitItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_EXIT, "&Выход", help='Выход из приложения')
        exitItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/file/exit.png'))
        filemenu.AppendItem(exitItem)

        configmenu = wx.Menu()
        self.show_statusbar = configmenu.Append(ID_SHOW_STATUSBAR, 'Отображать строку статуса', 'Отображать строку статуса', kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        configmenu.Check(self.show_statusbar.GetId(), True)
        self.preferencesItem = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, ID_OPTIONS, "&Параметры", help='Основные параметры приложения')
        self.preferencesItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/menu/preferences/preferences.png'))
        configmenu.AppendItem(self.preferencesItem)

        about = wx.Menu()
        helpmenu = wx.Menu()

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&Файл")
        menuBar.Append(configmenu, "&Настройки")
        menuBar.Append(helpmenu, "&Помощь")
        menuBar.Append(about, "&О программе")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        # toolbar
        tb = self.CreateToolBar(wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.NO_BORDER | wx.TB_FLAT | wx.TB_TEXT)
        tb.AddSimpleTool(ID_TOOLBAR_UPDIR, wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/toolbar/up.png'), 'Up one directory')
        tb.AddSimpleTool(ID_TOOLBAR_HOME, wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/toolbar/home.png'), 'Home')
        tb.AddSimpleTool(ID_TOOLBAR_REFRESH, wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/toolbar/refresh.png'), 'Refresh')
        tb.AddSeparator()
        tb.AddSimpleTool(ID_TOOLBAR_HELP, wx.Bitmap(ico_folder + '/icons/ui/toolbar/help.png'), 'Help')
        tb.Realize()

        # button panel
        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        button1 = wx.Button(self, ID_BUTTON_WRITE, "F5 Запись")
        button1.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        button1.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")

        button2 = wx.Button(self, ID_BUTTON_TRANSFER, "F6 Перенос")
        button2.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        button2.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")

        button3 = wx.Button(self, ID_BUTTON_CREATE_FOLDER, "F7 Созд. каталог")
        button3.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        button3.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")

        button4 = wx.Button(self, ID_BUTTON_REMOVE_FILE, "F8 Удалить")
        button4.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        button4.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")

        button5 = wx.Button(self, ID_BUTTON_RENAME, "F9 Перемеиновать")
        button5.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        button5.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")

        button6 = wx.Button(self, ID_EXIT, "F10 Выход")
        button6.SetBackgroundColour('#BFD8DF')
        button6.SetForegroundColour("#2F4D57")

        self.sizer2.Add(button1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(button2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(button3, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(button4, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(button5, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(button6, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.files_folder, 1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer2, 0,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        # events bindings
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ToggleStatusBar, self.show_statusbar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ShowMenu, self.preferencesItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExitProgramm)
        # create folder
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCreateFolder, id=ID_BUTTON_CREATE_FOLDER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCreateFolder, id=ID_FOLDER)
        # create file
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCreateFile, id=ID_NEW)
        # toolbar events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.UpDir, id=ID_TOOLBAR_UPDIR)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.Home, id=ID_TOOLBAR_HOME)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.RefreshFileCtrl, id=ID_TOOLBAR_REFRESH)
        # copy file
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.CopyFile, id=ID_COPY_FILE)
        # copy folder
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.CopyFolder, id=ID_COPY_FOLDER)

        # define size and icon for app
        size = (800, 600)
        self.SetSize(size)
        self.icon = wx.Icon(ico_folder + '/icons/app.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(self.icon)
        self.SetMinSize(size)

        self.Center()

    def UpDir(self, event):
        if self.files_folder.currentDir != self.files_folder.defaultDir:
            self.files_folder.currentDir = self.files_folder.getParentDir(self.files_folder.currentDir)
        filepath = self.files_folder.currentDir
        self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(filepath)

    def Home(self, event):
        self.files_folder.currentDir = self.files_folder.defaultDir
        self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(self.files_folder.defaultDir)

    def RefreshFileCtrl(self, event):
        self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(self.files_folder.currentDir)

    def OnCreateFolder(self, event):
        dlg = InputDialog(self, -1, 'Введите каталог', self.ico_folder, FolderValidator())
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result is not None:
            try:
                new_folder = self.files_folder.currentDir + dlg.result
                os.makedirs(new_folder)
            except OSError:
                wx.MessageBox("Вероятнее всего, такой файл или каталог уже существует!\nПожалуйста, дайте файлу другое имя.", 'Ошибка')
            except Exception, exc:
                wx.MessageBox("%s" % exc.message, "Ошибка")
            self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(self.files_folder.currentDir)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnCreateFile(self, event):
        dlg = InputDialog(self, -1, 'Введите имя файла и расширение', self.ico_folder, FileValidator())
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result is not None:
            try:
                new_file = self.files_folder.currentDir + dlg.result
                new_folders, filename = ntpath.split(dlg.result)
                if len(new_folders) > 2:
                    os.makedirs(self.files_folder.currentDir + new_folders)
                open(new_file, 'a').close()
            except OSError:
                wx.MessageBox("Вероятнее всего, такой файл или каталог уже существует!\nПожалуйста, дайте файлу другое имя.", 'Ошибка')
            except Exception, exc:
                wx.MessageBox("%s" % exc.message, "Ошибка")
            self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(self.files_folder.currentDir)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def CopyFile(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Укажите путь к файлу", "", "", "All files (*.*)|*.*", wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            filepath = dlg.GetPath()
            dir, filename = ntpath.split(filepath)
            shutil.copyfile(filepath, self.files_folder.currentDir+filename)
            self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(self.files_folder.currentDir)
            msg_dlg = MsgDlg(None, "Копирование завершено!")
            msg_dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def CopyMoveOperation(self, src, target, operation='copy'):
        for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
            dst_dir = src_dir.replace(src, target)
            if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
                os.mkdir(dst_dir)
            for file_ in files:
                src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
                dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
                if os.path.exists(dst_file):
                    os.remove(dst_file)
                if operation is 'copy':
                    shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)
                elif operation is 'move':
                    shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)

    def CopyFolder(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Укажите директорию", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            folderpath = dlg.GetPath()
            try:
                new_folder = folderpath.split('/')[-1]
                os.mkdir(new_folder)
            # if this folder already exists - then catch exception, ignore him, and copy files right now
            except OSError:
                pass
            self.CopyMoveOperation(folderpath, self.files_folder.currentDir+new_folder)
            self.files_folder.showFilesInDirectory(self.files_folder.currentDir)
            msg_dlg = MsgDlg(None, "Копирование завершено!")
            msg_dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def ShowMenu(self, event):
        self.options_frame.Show()

    def ToggleStatusBar(self, event):
        if self.show_statusbar.IsChecked():
            self.sb.Show()
        else:
            self.sb.Hide()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnExitProgramm(self, event):
        self.parent.Close()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        size = self.GetSize()
        self.files_folder.ResizeColumns(size.x)
        if not hasattr(self, 'sb'):
            self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.sb.SetStatusText(os.getcwd())
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    ico_folder = '..'
    frame = FileManager(None, -1, 'CloudStorage', ico_folder)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the error in a try exception block with a wx.PyDeadObjectError exception.

You can also remove the hasattr by using a AttributeError exception.

```
def OnSize(self, event):
    size = self.GetSize()
    self.files_folder.ResizeColumns(size.x)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    try:
        self.sb.SetStatusText(cwd)
    except AttributeError:
        self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar() 
        self.sb.SetStatusText(cwd)
    except wx.PyDeadObjectError:
        pass
    event.Skip()
```